# Best practice - Two functions with analog meaning

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I want to know what is the best practice for that situation.
Take those two functions

**Option 1** - TableController.cs

```
void deleteRow(Row myRow) {
    // do some control on myRow
    if (!(myRow.hasThatValue()) && (myRow.Title.StartsWith("xxx"))
        return;

    Rows.Remove(myRow);
    Events.OnRemoveRow(myRow);
}


void deleteRows(List<Row> myRows) {
   foreach (var r in myRows) {
       deleteRow(r);     // That call each time OnRemoveRow()
   }
}
```

**Option 2** - TableController.cs

```
void deleteRow(Row myRow) {
    // do some control on myRow
    if (!(myRow.hasThatValue()) && (myRow.Title.StartsWith("xxx"))
        return;

    Rows.Remove(myRow);
    Events.OnRemoveRow(myRow);   
}


void deleteRows(List<Row> myRows) {
   foreach (var r in myRows) {
        // do some control on myRow
        if (!(r.hasThatValue()) && (r.Title.StartsWith("xxx"))
            continue;

        Rows.Remove(myRow);
   }

   Events.OnReloadTable();     // That call only one time OnReloadTable()
}
```

Can you spot the difference? Say you have 1000 rows to delete and in the event OnRemoveRow you delete a row in a ListView, instead in the event OnReloadTable you clear and reload all rows in the ListView.

With option 1 you raise 1000 times the event that do a lot of work in the GUI, instead with option 2 you call only one time an event that reload all rows.

Using a benchmark is obviously that option 2 perform a lot better.

### So the question is:

There is an alternative or a better way that repeat two times the same code like in option 2 but with the good performance of that solution?

**Edit:**

@Ulf: In the example fixed return in loop with continue.

As suggested by HimBromBeere I try to explain a little better the problem:
**I have some redundand code for removing a row and I'm try to semplify much as possible**

From the point of view of performance having an event triggered for each row is a waste.
I'm looking at a way to write less code without impact performance.
From the answers I see two valid way to fix that problem.

Personally the first solution credits goes to: Yair Halberstadt

Having an internal method can solve the code redundancy.
A second solution is the answer of Mureinik, move the logic of remove a row to removing a list of row and use always a list of rows but create each time a new list of a single element seems a bit overheaded.

Comment: That completely depends on your environment and your context. However if you already *did* benchmarks why not trust them? When your code does what it should, what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: Note that you should `continue` in stead of `return` in option 2 in order to behave like option 1.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I want to reduce redundant codebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a third method `deleteRowInternal` containing shared logic.

```
 public void deleteRow(Row myRow) {
    deleteRowInternal(myRow);

    Events.OnRemoveRow(myRow);
}

private void deleteRowInternal(Row myRow) {
     // do some control on myRow
    if (!(myRow.hasThatValue()) && 
     (myRow.Title.StartsWith("xxx"))
         return;
    Rows.Remove(myRow);
}


 public void deleteRows(List<Row> myRows) {
       foreach (var r in myRows) {
       deleteRowInternal(r); 
     }
     Events.OnReloadTable();
 }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you'll want an `Events.OnReloadTable();` in the `deleteRows` method...

Comment: Nice solution having an internal method!

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, option #2 would perform better, but it repeats a lot of code between the two methods, and will result in a hard to maintain codebase.

I'd go for a third option, where `deleteRows` contains the better performing logic of option #2 and `deleteRow` reuses it:

```
void deleteRow(Row myRow) {
    deleteRows(new List<Row>(){myRow});
}


void deleteRows(List<Row> myRows) {
   foreach (var r in myRows) {
        // do some control on myRow
        if (!(myRow.hasThatValue()) && (myRow.Title.StartsWith("xxx"))
            return;

        Rows.Remove(myRow);
   }

   Events.OnReloadTable();
}
```

Comment: I would go for a fourth: don´t answer this question, as it´s completeley unclear what OP wants. Best practices tend to be quite opinion-based, in particular in this case where we don´t know anything about the OPs environment.

Comment: Good solution, but I think that creating a new List each time I remove a row cause a bit overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option is *inconsistent* with first one; providing that the `1st` is correct one (you want to remove all `rows` which have *that value* and don't start with `"xxx"`):

```
   ...
   foreach (var r in myRows) {
        // do some control on myRow
        if (!(myRow.hasThatValue()) && (myRow.Title.StartsWith("xxx"))
            return; // <- should be "continue";

        Rows.Remove(myRow); // <- should be "r"
   }
   ...
```

In order to avoid such errors I suggest *querying* with a help of *Linq*

```
// Let's change List<T> into more generic IEnumerable<T>
void deleteRows(IEnumerable<Row> myRows) {
   // Readbility: let's put it clear what we are going to remove
   var toRemove = myRows
     .Where(row => !row.Title?.StartsWith("xxx"))
     .Where(row => row.hasThatValue());

   // If you have RemoveRange in Rows collection - remove in one go
   // Rows.RemoveRange(toRemove);

   // If you don't have RemoveRange method, let's loop
   foreach (var r in toRemove)
     Rows.Remove(r);

   Events.OnReloadTable();     // That call only one time OnReloadTable()
}

// Taken from Mureinik's answer (except the collection class wrapper)
void void deleteRow(Row myRow) {
  deleteRows(new Row[] {myRow}); 
}
```